# static ip address allocation for public virtual server

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

```
Image image = new Image();
image.setCapacity(50L);

Guest guest = new Guest();
guest.setHostname("hostname1");
guest.setDomain("softlayer.com");
guest.setStartCpus(1l);
guest.setMaxMemory(1024l);
guest.setDatacenter(new Location());
guest.getDatacenter().setName("che01");

guest.setLocalDiskFlag(false);
guest.setHourlyBillingFlag(true);

guest.setOperatingSystemReferenceCode("UBUNTU_LATEST");

Component privateComponent = new Component();
Component publicComponent = new Component();

Vlan privateVlan = new Vlan();
privateVlan.setVlanNumber(1365L);
privateVlan.setId(2117919L);

Subnet privateSubnet = new Subnet();
privateSubnet.setId(1059121L);

privateComponent.setNetworkVlan(privateVlan);
privateComponent.setPrimarySubnet(privateSubnet);
guest.setPrimaryBackendNetworkComponent(privateComponent);

Vlan publicVlan = new Vlan();
publicVlan.setId(2117917L);
publicVlan.setVlanNumber(1290L);

Subnet primarySubnetVersion4 = new Subnet();
primarySubnetVersion4.setVersion(4L);
primarySubnetVersion4.setId(1547547L);
publicVlan.setPrimarySubnet(primarySubnetVersion4);

publicComponent.setNetworkVlan(publicVlan);
publicComponent.setPrimaryIpAddress("169.38.101.156");
guest.setPrimaryNetworkComponent(publicComponent);

Guest.service(client).createObject(guest);
```

How to configure a static ip address while creating a virtual server instead of assigning the dynamic IP address. I used the above code but its not working for me. please suggest a best way to configure the static ip address.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you won't be able to configure the ip address while creating the VSI. The provisioning process looks for an available ip address in the subnet an it is assigned to the VSI, this ip address is static so it will not change each time you turn on/off the VSI.

More info can be find in the documentation, for example in  [can-i-move-my-ip-address-one-server-another?](http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/can-i-move-my-ip-address-one-server-another) says:

> Each customer will receive an initial routed block of one primary IP address.  Primary IP addresses are bound to each individual server and cannot be moved unless the server is cancelled and replaced by a new server on the existing VLAN.

Below are some links that you can review about subnets and ip addresses.

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/can-i-move-my-ip-address-one-server-another

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/how-are-server-ip-addresses-assigned-softlayer-network

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/can-i-pick-my-servers-private-ip

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/virtual-machine-network-setup

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/learning/utilizing-subnets-and-ips

http://knowledgelayer.softlayer.com/faq/how-do-i-use-public-network

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply.  is it possible to assign specific subnet of a IP Address? For example subnet containing 20 IP address and we want to configure specific IP address for my VSI from the subnet.

Comment: You can specify the primary subnet while ordering the VSI, the subnet must be in the same VLan, the method SoftLayer_Network_Vlan::getPrimarySubnets returns the list of primary subnets into the vlan.

Comment: If you want to assign a ip address you need to login in the VSI and go to network configuration, but take account the following: this change will not be reflected by UI or API. If you try to assign an ip outside of a subnet routed on the vlan, you won’t get packet flow. The provisioning system could assign the same ip when a new VSI has been ordered , you will get conflicts, so then you'd have to be maintaining the ip addressing of all your VSIs.

Comment: I mean , have to assign static private IP Address from existing subnets.just i tried with privateComponent.setPrimaryIpAddress("10.162.13.57"); but its not working for me.

Comment: It is not possible to assign ip address by UI or API, the same when using languages like java, python, etc.